# Node.js Babel build and npm module-alias

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, alias, babeljs

I'm using [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) for my Node.js + Express.js project, running it with Babel for ES2015 support.

App works perfect when started with `babel-node`, however, if I first build it with `babel` (from `package.json`):

```
"build": "babel ./app --out-dir ./app_dist"
```

And then start:

```
"start": "node ./app_dist/bin/www"
```

It obviously cannot find the correct path specified with module-alias. Instead of looking into `app_dist`, Node.js searches for import in `app`, finds ES2015 `import` directive which it does not understand and throws:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

If I change aliases before start of that build, from `app` to `app_dist`, it works, but the question is, how to map those aliases (or how to use different `_moduleAliases` configuration) so that app resolves the paths correctly on development and production?

Maybe there is another way to alias modules with such stack? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I prefer use [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found solution for this issue.

In order to set the relative path aliases with [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias#advanced-usage), they shoul be defined not in `package.json`, but in JavaScript file inside the root directory that will be transpiled with Babel.

In my case, creating an `aliases.js` script inside `config` directory like this:

```
import path from 'path';
import moduleAlias from 'module-alias';

moduleAlias.addAlias('@root', path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'));
```

Will result in path resolving relatively to the current working directory, solving described problem.